# Show landscape video from portrait viewcontroller

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, screen-rotation

I don't understand how I can force my video player in landscape in my otherwise portrait app.

In my AppDelegate I have this:

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
}
```

In my presenting ViewController I have this:

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
}

public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
{
    return false;
}
```

And in my VideoViewController I have this:

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
}

public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
}

public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
{
        return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight;
}

public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
{
    return true;
}
```

As you can see I have tried to override each existing method. I am all out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I noticed a warning in the log: `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`, but I am setting the `rootViewController` properly, I am using the child view controllers properly, and I am not presenting the video before `viewDidAppear`. Is this related to my issue?

Comment: have you tried in your ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation - return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight
?

Comment: @PavelGatilov: as you can see, I am allowing all rotations, but nothing is happening... Or do you mean in the presenting viewcontroller?

Comment: in your VideoViewController instead of just returning true for ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, try to return true only for landscape left or right orientations.

Comment: @PavelGatilov I did, it doesn't even get called.